# Javascript/jquery converting string to datetime (using New date in javascript) to pass to .net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to convert my string to a date format to pass it in a way that my mvc c# understands it.

Please read the following, where I explain the problem step by step.

I have an input

```
<input name="EgresoStJohns" class="form-control txtOut"/>
```

When the user saves the form, I do the following in Jquery

```
var dateOut = $(".txtOut").val();
```

dateOut becomes something like this, depending on the date that the user picks: 30/03/2017

Then I try to parse my date, so the controller in c# mvc understands that I want to send a dd/mm/yy, otherwise, if I send 30/03/2017 the controller will understand month=30 and it will conver the entire date to null.

```
var DateToSend = new Date(parseInt(dateOut));
DateToSend = DateToSend.getDate() + "/" + (DateToSend.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + DateToSend.getFullYear();
```

However, inmmediately after doing the New Date, the input ALWAYS becomes "31/12/1969", so I am unable to work with it.

What can I do to solve this inconvenience?

Comment: Why are you passing `dateOut` to `parseInt()`?

Comment: `parseInt(dateOut)` return `30` - you would need to split the value based on `/` to get the components

Comment: @Pointy if I dont parseInt, I get "NaN"

Comment: Well getting the completely wrong date isn't much better than that. Search for date parsing questions here - there are *thousands* of them.

Comment: Of course it would be better to just change the culture on the server to one that expects dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, or to create a custom ModelBinder for dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're certain that will be the entered date format, you could do something like this.  All it's doing is reversing the month/day prior to creating the new `Date` object.

```
var dateOut = $(".txtOut").val().split("/");
var dateToSend = new Date(dateOut[1] + "/" + dateOut[0] + "/" + dateOut[2]);
```

Comment: To solve my problem, I just put the month first so c# would understand it

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use `moment.js` to parse your data in your client side.

First is to make the field `type="date"` then we can modify the field to format it `DD/MM/YYYY` by using `moment.js`

Second is we can add CSS to tweak the date field

then we can get the value by using `moment.js` again to format of `MM/DD/YYYY`

```js
//format field
$(".txtOut").on("change", function() {
    this.setAttribute(
        "data-date",
        moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        .format( this.getAttribute("data-date-format") )
    )
}).trigger("change")


$(function(e){
  $("#btn").click(function(e){
     //parse date using moment.js, then use this to pass in your ajax.
     var DateToSend = moment($(".txtOut").val()).format("MM/DD/YYYY");     
     console.log(DateToSend);
     //format it whatever you want base on this docs https://momentjs.com/docs/
     console.log(moment($(".txtOut").val()).format("MMMM DD, YYYY"))
  })
})
```

```css
.txtOut {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; height: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.txtOut:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 3px;
    content: attr(data-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}

.txtOut::-webkit-datetime-edit, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

.txtOut::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.js"></script>
<input name="EgresoStJohns" class="form-control txtOut" type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" value="2017-03-30">
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed question, I really apreciate the time you took. However, I´m going with the other answer since it´s a more simple way to solve my specific problem.